# Conditional interpolation with subject

Tags: angular, conditional-statements, interpolation, behaviorsubject

I have an `Subject` which provides me with `number`. In my template, I would like to render this number in braces, if it is higher than 0.

Theoretically something like this (this does not work though):

`{{ ($number | async) > 0 ? '('+ ($number| async)  +')' : '' }}`

How would I render an subject, based on a condition of its own value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ngIf` conditions and assign the observable result to variable

```
<div *ngIf="$number | async as num"> 
   <div *ngIf="num> 0"> '(' {{num}} ')' </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. In my case, I used a `span` as I add the number to a inner html text.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `as` notation in combination with `*ngIf` directive.

Here is how you do it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8q7czz

```
<p *ngIf="obs$ | async as num">
  {{  num > 5 ? '('+ num  +')' : num }}
</p>
```